# How to continuously add custom vocabulary to speech to text model?

Tags: python, database, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently trying to write a program that organizes pet data based on their names.

Now I would like to create a sort of assistent mode where the app listens to the user while e.g. preparing food and displays the data when it recognizes a name.

My problem is that there are countless pet names and they can be highly custom like e.g "Desktop". Or maybe "Uiona". Also pronunciation can be highly different.

So my idea was that the user needs to record the name once on pet creation and the app does compare the ongoing audio stream with a database of saved records.

> -Whats a good approach to create said behavior?

> -Do I need a custom speech to text model and retrain it every time?

Thank you all in advance!